# React native - redux | cant fetch value from json | how to display result through dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show result in list view.I am using redux to maintain props and state.

getting value in console with each object, can anyone help how to get on screen.

here is my function in action :

I can successfully print getData in console, but after that not showing in screen. any idea ?

Need help in defining dataBlob, sectionID and rowIDs.

Hope this information help.

```
class testrnapp extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
    this.bindMethods();
}

bindMethods() {
    if (! this.bindableMethods) {
        return;
    }   

    for (var methodName in this.bindableMethods) {
        this[methodName] = this.bindableMethods[methodName].bind(this);
    }
}

getInitialState() {
    var getSectionData = (dataBlob, sectionID) => {
        return dataBlob[sectionID];
    }

    var getRowData = (dataBlob, sectionID, rowID) => {
        return dataBlob[sectionID + ':' + rowID];
    }

    return {
        loaded : false,
        dataSource : new ListView.DataSource({
            getSectionData          : getSectionData,
            getRowData              : getRowData,
            rowHasChanged           : (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            sectionHeaderHasChanged : (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
        })
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

fetchData () {
    fetch(API_URL).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseData) => {
        var journals = responseData.journals,

            length = journals.length,
            dataBlob = {},
            sectionIDs = [],
            rowIDs = [],
            journal,
            title,
            titleLength,
            i,
            j;
 console.log(responseData.journals);
 console.log(journals.length);


         for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            journal = journals[i];
            //var  key = i;

            sectionIDs.push(responseData._id);

            dataBlob[responseData._id] = journal.journal;
            rowIDs[i] = [];
            rowIDs[i].push(journal._id);
            dataBlob[responseData._id + ':' + journal._id] = journal;


        }

        this.setState({
            dataSource : this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs),
            loaded     : true
        });

    }).done();        
}

render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
        return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return this.renderListView();
}

renderLoadingView() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>User List</Text>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActivityIndicatorIOS
                    animating={!this.state.loaded}
                    style={[styles.activityIndicator, {height: 80}]}
                    size="large"
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

renderListView() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>User List</Text>
            </View>
            <ListView
                dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                style      = {styles.listview}
                renderRow  = {this.renderRow}
                renderSectionHeader = {this.renderSectionHeader}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

renderSectionHeader(sectionData, sectionID) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{sectionData}</Text>
        </View>
    ); 
}
    };

 Object.assign(testrnapp.prototype, {
bindableMethods : {
    renderRow : function (rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressRow(rowData, sectionID)}>
                <View style={styles.rowStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.title} {rowData.desc} {rowData.date}</Text>        
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    },
    onPressRow : function (rowData, sectionID) {
        var buttons = [
            {
                text : 'Cancel'
            },
            {
                text    : 'OK',
                onPress : () => this.createCalendarEvent(rowData, sectionID)
            }
        ]
        AlertIOS.alert('User\'s Email is ' + rowData.email, null, null);
    }

}
});
```

JSON formate for data --->

```
    {
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "57645011e78a006c85d9e2ce"
    },
    "user": {
      "$oid": "57645011e78a006c85d9e2cc"
    },
   "journals": [
    {
      "title": " day at the park",
      "desc": "Went to a concert with friends today, it was good to catch up. I haven’t seen them in sooo long! ....",
      "feeling": 1,
      "date": {
        "$date": 1466194027825
      },
      "deleteFl": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5764586be78a006c85d9e2d9"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Just one good ",
      "desc": "Nothing interesting happened today, but it was a good... ",
      "feeling": 2,
      "date": {
        "$date": 1466194592885
      },
      "deleteFl": false,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "57645aa0e78a006c85d9e2e4"
      }
    },
```

Comment: How did you map dispatch getJournals()? Can you post your reducer code?

Comment: hi Abdullah, here is my reducers function.

export default createReducers(initialState, {
    [JOURNALS_RECEIVED_SUCCESS] : (state, data) => {
        return {
            ...state,
            journals: data.payload
        }
    },
});

Comment: How do you provide the dispatch function to the returned function from getJournals? I need to see the full cycle in order to know what your problem is. Can you edit your post component (with your connect code)?

Comment: please  check code above. its printing getData in console with successfully array. 
Community says that "create the datasource and a copy of the array and save them to state."

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional code. However, I still don't see how ```dispatch``` is being provided or where ```getJournals``` is used. I need more context in order to help you

Comment: Hi abdullah, i have updated a question, please check once again

Comment: Updated code one more time, getting only last entry, can any one tell me how to gett all the entries ? do i have to run the loop ? if yes then where ?